# Why is MahApps unable to find Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, mahapps.metro

I would like to use the `Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml` in my WPF project.

**I added the line :**

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
```

Like it's written in the documentation.

**My app.xaml is now :**

```
<Application x:Class="myAPP.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls.TabControl.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

VS shows me that an error has been encountered when seeking for the dictionary resource :

```
pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for tab control](https://mahapps.com/docs/styles/tabcontrol) is not up-to-date. In [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/releases/tag/2.0.0), all tab control styles were moved to the `Controls.TabControl.xaml` resource dictionary that is [already included in `Controls.xaml`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/272e5599fb82d6a129f0b0cb91ea8dc16f7d50f1/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.xaml#L29).

See the related change on GitHub: [(GH-3587) All TabControl styles in one resource dictionary](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/commit/9e73e57db88c1ac4600447b69fb0ec6a313942ed#diff-7683c73289bbc16499c0727773b881e59876249b730db12adb7bae5fb17511c1)

In order to use the different styles, you have to replace your `TabControl` with the *MahApps* equivalent.

- For the [*AnimatedTabControl*](https://mahapps.com/docs/styles/tabcontrol#animatedtabcontrol) use `<mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl>`
- For the [*AnimatedSingleRowTabControl*](https://mahapps.com/docs/styles/tabcontrol#animatedsinglerowtabcontrol) use `<mah:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>`